# How to move all items of integer array recursively to first cell?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm having a hard time struggling with recursion.
I need to write a function that is recursively called to compare two arrays of integers.
The function receives the two arrays and their corresponding length.

The arrays contain numbers.
My goal is eventually to move all items of each array to the first cell of the array, and have the exit condition compare the two first cells of the arrays.
Because this is an integer array, I fail to understand how to "concatenate" the numbers from the next cell to the previous one, and generally, how to do the whole thing.
I'd very much appreciate an answer, or a hint.

**Explanation:**

The function will take two arrays an their lengths as arguments say [123, 456, 7891] and [12345, 6, 78, 91]. My function needs to return whether these two are equal.

My idea is that I somehow recursively move all the items in the two array to the first cell, correspondingly, and then compare the cells in the final return condition, thanks!

this obviously could be done in another way, it doesnt matter to me which way works as long as it does :D

**[edit]:**

Here are some possible comparisons:

```
compare( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) => SAME
compare( [12, 34, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) => SAME  
compare( [12, 34, 5], [123, 45]) => SAME
compare( [1, 2], [5, 6]) => DIFFER
```

Comment: What does it mean to concatenate a number?

Comment: what i mean is that if my original array looks like [235][236543][123] i eventually want to achieve [235236543123] ( the content of the following cells dont matter ).

Comment: Some example code would be useful.

Comment: Sounds almost like you want to compare a sequence of numbers by using string comparison of the numbers bunched together.

Comment: i added an example. please note that i cant use loops.

Comment: I think to combine all the elements in order to compare the array is a bad idea.

Comment: This is still unclear. What do you mean by "the content of the following cells dont matter "? Following cells in which array? Also, where does the exit condition come in? If you could post what you have done up until now, the code fragment could make what you are trying to say more clear.

Comment: i dont really have a code fragement. what i meant by the following cells dont matter is that when i somehow acheieve having "235236543123" in the first cell of every array, it doesnt really matter to me what the following cells contain. i think the example i gave in the edited version is more clear. thanks alot

Comment: "My idea is that I somehow recursively move all the items in the two array to the first cell" — this idea is wrong, don't try it at home. You are supposed to take a function that compares arrays of some length, *don't worry about how to write it just yet*, you take it and make it into a function that compares arrays of a bigger length. Then you figure out how to write the original function in the first place. That's how recursion works.

Comment: well if my idea is wrong then im kinda lost since i dont really understand how to work with two arrays in a recursion, my brain is limited to one only

Comment: @user2502445 your question wasn't very clear at all. I've added some example inputs/outputs. Please make sure that these reflect what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Recursive solution to representational equality

In this case, instead of checking for array equality (see below) we check that the numbers represented as strings and then concatenated are equal. For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] === [12,34,5] === [123,45]
```

The idea is that we [reduce/fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) over each array, with a string of the representation as our final value, and the empty string as our initial value, taking each integer, converting it to a string, and concatenating it at the end of our result. We then find ourselves with two strings, which we compare for equality.

Note that there are several problems with my solution.

1. Firstly, I do not do any bound checking for the string operation, so the following code will merrily trample all over your memory.
2. We also do not keep track of the end of the result, which means that each concatenation will need to walk through the result string, which is not an efficient way of doing it.
3. A limitation of the itoa implementation given is that it will not work correctly for the largest negative integer.

The general idea remains the same though. In a nice programming language you could just write:

```
(eq?     
  (reduce concat "" (map tostr [1,2,3,4,5] ))
  (reduce concat "" (map tostr [1,2,3,4,5] )))
```

or equivalent; but this is C, so we have to do it the hard way:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SAME 0
#define DIFFER 1

void reverse(char s[]);
void itoa(int n, char s[]);

void reduce_to_string(char *result, int values[], int values_len){
  char tmpstr[256] = "";

  if( values_len == 0 ){ return; }

  // convert the first number to a string, writing the representation to tmpstr
  itoa(values[0], tmpstr);

  // concatenate the first number with the accumulated string
  result = strcat(result, tmpstr);

  // recur with a smaller array.
  return reduce_to_string(result, &values[1], (values_len-1));
}

int compare_representation(int a[], int a_len, int b[], int b_len){
  char a_as_string[512] = "";
  char b_as_string[512] = "";

  reduce_to_string(a_as_string, a, a_len);
  reduce_to_string(b_as_string, b, b_len);

  if( 0 == strcmp(a_as_string, b_as_string) ){ return SAME;}

  return DIFFER;
}


int main(void){

  int b[] = {6,7,8,9};
  int b_len = 4;

  int c[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int c_len = 5;

  int d[] = {67, 89};
  int d_len = 2;

  assert(SAME == compare_representation(b,b_len,d,d_len));
  assert(DIFFER == compare_representation(b,b_len,c,c_len));

  return 0;
}



/*
 * The following are from K&R C, second edition.
 */

/* reverse:  reverse string s in place. page 62 */
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}

/* itoa:  convert n to characters in s. page 64*/
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -n;          /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

#### Syntax explanation:

If you're new to C, using `&a[1]` for the tail of array 'a' may not be clear.

(when I say tail, I mean all other elements except the first one.)

Breaking it down to English `&a[1]` says something like: "the address of the second value in array 'a'". Why does this work? because in C, arrays are nothing but pointers to the start of the memory used to store the variables, so taking the address of the second variable essentially gives you an array with one less element in it. To make sure we take into consideration that the array is smaller, we also decrease the array length variable 'a_len' before passing it to the next function call.

### Recursive solution and iterative solution (for array equality)

Both `compare_*` functions perform a comparison between two integer arrays, checking that the arrays are identical.

```
#include <assert.h>

#define SAME 0
#define DIFFER 1

int compare_recursive(int a[], int a_len, int b[], int b_len){
  if( a_len != b_len ){ return DIFFER; }
  if( a_len == 0 && b_len == 0 ){ return SAME; }
  if(a[0] == b[0]){
    return compare_recursive(&a[1], (a_len-1), &b[1], (b_len-1) );
  }else{
    return DIFFER;
  }
}

int compare_iterative(int a[], int a_len, int b[], int b_len){
  int i;
  if( a_len != b_len ){ return DIFFER; }
  for(i = 0; i < a_len; i++){
    if( a[i] != b[i] ){ return DIFFER; }
  }
  return SAME;
}

int main(void){
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int a_len = 5;

  int b[] = {6,7,8,9};
  int b_len = 4;

  int c[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int c_len = 5;

  assert(DIFFER == compare_recursive(a,a_len,b,b_len));
  assert(SAME == compare_recursive(a,a_len,c,c_len));

  assert(DIFFER == compare_iterative(a,a_len,b,b_len));
  assert(SAME == compare_iterative(a,a_len,c,c_len));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think this is not right since if the arrays are different in size it doesnt mean they are not equal . since in my case equality is defined by the numbers , no matter in what cell they are ( [123][45][6] ) is equal to [12345][6] and also equal [12][34][5][6].

Comment: Then you're not comparing arrays for equality. Are you actually worried about the string representation of the numbers?

Comment: Yes, I need the numbers in both strings will be equal and in the same order.

Comment: No, the numbers will **not** be equal. Their **concatenated string representations** will be. This was unclear in your question. The solution is a bit more involved. Have a read and tell me what you think.

Comment: You can fix the efficiency concern of `reduce_to_string` by passing `result + strlen(result)` to the first parameter in the recursive call. Once you make that change, you don't need `tmpstr` anymore, you can apply `itoa()` on `result` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to number 'concatenation':

If you really want to 'concatenate' two numbers, a possible way of doing that is:

Suppose you have two numbers n1 and n2 where number of digits in n2 is m. Then the way to concatenate them, as per your example is n1 * 10<sup>m</sup> + n2.

So for 235 and 236543, concatenation would be 235 * 10<sup>6</sup> + 23645 = 235236543